# Screen.currentResolution with Unity 5.2.1

Tags: screen-resolution, unity-game-engine

We are using Unity to develop a desktop application, and we were using Unity 4 previously. Now we have upgraded our project to Unity 5 (5.2.1). We have an issue with setting the screen resolution. We used `Screen.SetResolution (Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height, true);` in Unity 4 to set the resolution and it works fine, but in Unity 5, `Screen.currentResolution.width` doesn't give the correct value.

Is there anything new with Unity 5.2.1 that could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for either:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html

Or:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resolution-width.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resolution-height.html

Current resolution might only give you what you expect if your player believes that it's running in Window mode?

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-currentResolution.html

Comment: You're mostly right here. As an example, say you have a monitor that is 1920 x 1080 and a player window that is 800 x 600. Screen.currentResolution would return 1920 x 1080 (The resolution of the monitor), Screen.width and Screen.height would return the 800 x 600 value (The resolution of the player window), and Resolution.width and Resolution.height should in theory return whatever it's been assigned, as Resolution is a struct-like class that represents a display, storing a height, width and refresh rate.

Comment: Thank you guys , we will check it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just fixed it by using another way:

```
Screen.SetResolution(Display.main.systemWidth, Display.main.systemHeight, true);
```

It worked for me (the others didn't).